# Call a function after the Job has completed Full Execution

Tags: c#, quartz.net

We are using Quartz.Net to trigger jobs on a schedule in a Windows Service.

I have a situation where I have to Trigger a job every `5 minutes` from `Start DateTime` till `End DateTime`.

After the job is completed we need to calculate the `Next Start DateTime` and `Next End DateTime` and save to the DB -

For this I tried to override the `JobListener` which has a method: `JobWasExecuted`

```
public class xPTJobListener : JobListenerSupport
{
    public override string Name { get { return "xPTJobListener"; } }

    public override void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {

        var dataMap = context.MergedJobDataMap;
        var schedule = (MyDTO)dataMap["Schedule"];

        using (var logger = new xPTLogger())
        {
            logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Information, string.Format("Inside JobWasExecuted() - [{0}] - ", schedule.Id));
        }

        base.JobWasExecuted(context, jobException);
    }
}
```

and also the `TriggerComplete` in the `TriggerListener`

```
public class xPTTriggerListener : TriggerListenerSupport
{
    public override string Name { get { return "xPTTriggerListener"; } }

    public override void TriggerComplete(ITrigger trigger, IJobExecutionContext context, SchedulerInstruction triggerInstructionCode)
    {

        var dataMap = context.MergedJobDataMap;
        var schedule = (MyDTO)dataMap["Schedule"];

        using (var logger = new xPTLogger())
        {
            logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Information, string.Format("Inside Trigger Complete - [{0}] - ", schedule.Id));
        }


        base.TriggerComplete(trigger, context, triggerInstructionCode);

    }
}
```

But the problem with above methods is that they are both executed each time the job is called.

So if I have a Job which runs from `12:01 AM` and ends `12:02 AM` every 5 seconds - Both these methods get called `12 times`

What I need is to call a method only once after the One Job iteration has Ended - (After the Job is executed 12 Times)?

How do I do this in Quartz?

**EDIT**

Creating the Triggers

```
public static ITrigger GenerateTrigger(RouteMonitorScheduleDTO routeSchedule, double fGmtOffset, xPTLogger logger)
{
    ITrigger trigger = null;

    switch (routeSchedule.ScheduleInfo.PeriodType)
    {
        case PeriodTypeEnum.Once:
            trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity(string.Format("trigger_{0}", routeSchedule.RouteScheduleId), DefaultGroup)
                        .StartAt(routeSchedule.DepartureDateTime)
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInMinutes(5))
                        .EndAt(routeSchedule.ArrivalDateTime.AddMinutes(5))
                        .Build();
            break;
        case PeriodTypeEnum.Daily:
        case PeriodTypeEnum.WeekDays:
        case PeriodTypeEnum.Weekly:
        case PeriodTypeEnum.Monthly:
            var schedule = routeSchedule.ScheduleInfo;        
            var cronExpresion = xPTCronBuilder.GenerateCronExpression(
                                    schedule.PeriodType,                         
                                    schedule.ScheduleStringValue, 
                                    fGmtOffset,             
                                    routeSchedule.DepartureDateTime,
                                    routeSchedule.ArrivalDateTime.AddMinutes(5), 5);
            trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity(string.Format("trigger_{0}", routeSchedule.RouteScheduleId), DefaultGroup)
                        .WithCronSchedule(cronExpresion)
                        .Build();
            break;
    }

    return trigger;
}
```

**EDIT**
Trigger with Cron:

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithIdentity(string.Format("trigger_{0}", 1), "Group1")
.WithCronSchedule("0 0-45/5 7-7 ? * TUE,WED *").Build();
```

As you can see from above cron expression it will run from `7 AM to 7:45 AM` every `5 minutes` every `Tuesday` and `Wednesday`.

So 1 iteration is `7AM to 7:45 AM` on `Tuesday`, the Next is `7 AM to 7:45` on `Wednesday`. I need to call a function after each Iteration has completed.

So let's say that when the Last Trigger is fired for `7:45 AM on Tuesday` - I need to call the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "entire job"? You're executing the job 12 times, so why do you expect these methods to be called only once?

Comment: That's what I need - after one full iteration I need to fire a method to calculate the next start and End Date

Comment: Perhaps a static counter on your job class?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck That won't work as the number of times the job has to be executed varies

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the job(s) up?

Comment: @stuartd I have added the way the Trigger is created - it is using Cron expression

Comment: What if you changed your TriggerComplete function to look at trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc() and only perform your calculation if this returns null?

Comment: @DawoodAwan Can't you give `JobDataMap` where you include the number of times it will be executed to the Trigger, then you can compare the `static int count` with the value in the `JobDataMap` to see if the final method needs to be run. (`context.Trigger.JobDataMap` in the execute method)

Comment: @sgmoore I don't think that will work with Daily jobs - I think it will only work on Jobs that has a limited End Date

Comment: @AlexanderDerck that will mean adding the Counter to somewhere in the DB - because if the service is restarted the service will loose count.

Comment: @DawoodAwan Without a database how else would you keep track of the times your job has run when the program isn't running? If the job has run 6 times already, you won't know unless you save that somewhere afaik with in-memoryscheduler.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can do this using ITriggerListener in the following way:

```
public class xPTTriggerListener : TriggerListenerSupport {
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "xPTTriggerListener"; }
    }

    public override void TriggerComplete(ITrigger trigger, IJobExecutionContext context, SchedulerInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
        if (triggerInstructionCode == SchedulerInstruction.DeleteTrigger) {
            // means this trigger won't be fired again - now recalculate your dates in database
        }
        base.TriggerComplete(trigger, context, triggerInstructionCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question above I have already tried this. But it is not what I need. I need to call the function after one complete iteration

Comment: @DawoodAwan Note condition triggerInstructionCode == SchedulerInstruction.DeleteTrigger. This will execute only once, after last iteration.

Comment: @DawoodAwan I actually had a chance to verify this today and it indeed works as expected: whole TriggerComplete will run many times (say 12 times), but instruction will be SchedulerInstruction.DeleteTrigger only once - on the last iteration when trigger will not fire any more.

Comment: I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @DawoodAwan You mean my answer does not work? You mentioned another person.

Comment: Yes Evk your answer only works for triggers with end time

Comment: In description of your problem your triggers are with end time. So it does not work for triggers without end time but with fixed number of repeats?

Comment: @DawoodAwan I just verified that it does work for trigger without end time, but with fixed repeat count (if it does not have end time or fixed repeats - when does it end after all?), so you need to elaborate more on your conditions when it does not work.

Comment: Evk Try this Cron Expression: 0 45-0/5 7-7 ? * TUE,WED *

Comment: @DawoodAwan I don't see when trigger with this expression ends - it seems to be run forever. I thought you were asking how to detect when trigger has finished it's iterations and won't run any more, but I don't understand what do you want to achieve with this endless expression.

Comment: Please check my Edit

Comment: Well that is completely different story. Trigger has no sense of such "iterations" - it will just run next time in next Tuesday. What if use trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc() in TriggerComplete in listener, and if next execution is say more that 12 hours in the future - run your method? Should work in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating another job triggered once in a minute for the given period by using the `StartTime` or `EndTime` as global values?

In addition to this, you could also check the `EndTime` value before calling your action method. In this case you execute the action if the current time is equal to or near to `DateTime.Now()` or something similar to that:

```
//...
if(endtime == DateTime.Now())
{
    //call your action
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I use JobListener for this. 
TriggerListener is unreliable, as it doesn't get called if the trigger is triggered manually.

Example:

```
// Quartz.IJobDetail job1 = Quartz.JobBuilder.Create() .... .Build();
// Quartz.ITrigger trigger = Quartz.TriggerBuilder.Create() .... .Build();

this.m_scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(new SimpleJobListener(),
    Quartz.Impl.Matchers.KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(new JobKey(job1.Key.Name, job1.Key.Group)
    )
);


this.m_scheduler.ListenerManager.AddTriggerListener(new SimpleTriggerListener(),
    Quartz.Impl.Matchers.KeyMatcher<TriggerKey>.KeyEquals(new TriggerKey(trigger.Key.Name, trigger.Key.Group)
    )
);
```

Listeners:

```
using Quartz;


namespace ReportMailer
{


    public class SimpleTriggerListener
        : ITriggerListener
    {
        protected string m_jobName;

        string ITriggerListener.Name => this.m_jobName;


        public SimpleTriggerListener(string name)
        {
            this.m_jobName = name;
        }

        public SimpleTriggerListener()
            : this("Job_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        { }



        System.Threading.Tasks.Task ITriggerListener.TriggerComplete(
            ITrigger trigger, 
            IJobExecutionContext context, 
            SchedulerInstruction triggerInstructionCode,
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("TriggerComplete");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task ITriggerListener.TriggerFired(
            ITrigger trigger, 
            IJobExecutionContext context, 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("TriggerFired");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task ITriggerListener.TriggerMisfired(
            ITrigger trigger, 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("TriggerMisfired");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> ITriggerListener.VetoJobExecution(
            ITrigger trigger, 
            IJobExecutionContext context, 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("VetoJobExecution");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    } // End Class SimpleTriggerListener 



    public class SimpleJobListener
        : IJobListener
    {

        protected string m_jobName;

        string IJobListener.Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_jobName;
            }
        }


        public SimpleJobListener(string name)
        {
            this.m_jobName = name;
        }

        public SimpleJobListener()
            : this("Job_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        { }



        System.Threading.Tasks.Task IJobListener.JobExecutionVetoed(
            IJobExecutionContext context, 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("JobExecutionVetoed");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task IJobListener.JobToBeExecuted(
            IJobExecutionContext context, 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("JobToBeExecuted");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task IJobListener.JobWasExecuted(
            IJobExecutionContext context, 
            JobExecutionException jobException, 
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("JobWasExecuted");
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    } // End Class SimpleJobListener 


}
```