# Quartz run job again N minutes after completed

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have some repeating quartz jobs that use `SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForever(60)`. Lets say the job initially gets scheduled at 10:02am and runs for 5 minutes completing at 10:07am.

Right now it is getting scheduled to run again at 11:02am but I want it to run again 60 minutes after completing so it should be scheduled at 11:07am instead.

Is there any way to change the scheduling to do this? Or should I use a one time job that creates a new job each time it completes?

Comment: You will have to update the original trigger. I.e. in your job's execute method you need to lookup and update the existing trigger. Alternatively, you can use some job chaining engine that can automatically refire your job after its completion etc.. For example, QuartzDesk job chaining engine provides this functionality and it allows you to externalize the job chaining logic from your application (Note: I am biased here). See https://www.quartzdesk.com/documentation/features#job-chaining

Answer (score 0):

Use `TriggerListener` - see [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/TriggerListeners.html) for some examples in Quartz cookbook.

You will override `triggerComplete` and in there you will add your rescheduling code:

```
public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
    // check here the triggerInstructionCode value and reschedule your job
    super.triggerComplete(trigger, context, triggerInstructionCode);
}
```

Example for registering a TriggerListener with the scheduler to listen to a specific trigger:

```
scheduler.getListenerManager().addTriggerListener(myTriggerListener, keyEquals(triggerKey("myTriggerName", "myTriggerGroup")));
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667767/3883957).